# Rails repeat form on page for each record of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, form-for

Say I have a model pets.  In my controller I have

@pets = current_user.pets.all

In my view I will have something like:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @pets  do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name %> 
    <%= f.input :type %>
    <%= f.input :age %>

 <% end %>
```

I want it so that a form is created for every item in @pets, but nothing I've tried has worked, and googling has been unhelpful.  Seems like it should be something easy.

Comment: what are the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try with this

```
@pets = current_user.pets
```